# Android: find caller of onDestroy()

Tags: android

A have an app deployed to some enterprise devices.
The app causes problems since updating to android 11 because the app is restarted without an exception.
I write log for the activity lifecycle and see the onDestoy()-method of an "always-running-activity" is called. Always running means it is the mainmenu and created at app-start and killed at app-end.

At the moment of the destroy, the activity is not at the top of the stack, so it can't be caused by user interaction. Also, the activity can only be killed by pressing specific closing-button and this closing-button was not pressed.

I think device management or something is causing the kill. If it's caused by Out Of Memory Error or system, the onDestroy will not be called, I think.
I am not able to reproduce this. But it's happening really often and not below android 11.

**Is there a way to log something like stacktrace to get the cause of the onDestroy-call?**

The app runs without major problems since nearly 10 years until the customer decided to upgrade to android 11.

**Edit:** Let me clearify:
I have an activity stack:
A -> B. A is a main menu activity and is always running. Always running means: A is started with the app and should be run as long as the app runs. B is the current foreground-activity at top of the stack. User is interacting with it.

What's happening:
While the user is interacting with B, the whole app finishes. I can see in my log onDestroy() is called within A and B.

A had a focus on the "background-activity" in my statements because the user has no possibility to interact with A while B is running. A is in background and is still killed.
So the user cannot be responsible for killing the app using the UI.
The problem is **not** that A is killed. The problem is: The whole app is killed.
The source code of B is simple and not changed in the last 10 years. Every exception is logged by an exception handler. There was no logged exception in B.
If the app runs oom (I can't imagine that) and is killed by the system (then no exception will be logged), onDestroy() should not be called.

So summarized:

- Every activity in the stack (even the one in foreground) is killed and the onDestoy()-calls are logged.
- No exception was logged

Comment: Destroying activities that are not in foreground has always been android policy, I'm surprised it even worked that long. Curious why is that an issue? You're not running tasks in stopped activity right?

Comment: @Pawel My whole app is destroyed (not killed because all activities call onDestroy()). The user is interacting with the foreground-activity and the app is closing. There is no exception and onDestroy is called even on the background-activities before going down. I am trying to find out whats causing this. I am not running tasks in stopped activities

Comment: @Ef Ge I suggest you to use Firebase Crashlytics which usually is able to identify those exceptions which are missed by the Logcat.

Comment: If issue is system battery/memory management it's going to be impossible to pin point, this varies by android version and most manfuacturers interfere with it as well. But assuming that your app won't collapse as soon as user leaves its activity is incorrect by design. If for some reason you need you app process to run you have to pin it to the foreground with foreground service.

Comment: There is no such thing as "always running activity" in Android.  Activities not in the foreground may be killed at any time, even if there's another activity in the foreground.

Comment: I have updated my question as it wasn't clear. The app is in foreground and the whole app is killed

Comment: What you are describing is very odd.  It sounds like something is causing all the activities in the stack to be finished.  Are there any relevant messages in logcat (make sure you aren't filtering to just your app; look at everything).

Answer (score 0):

The system can and will destroy activities that are not running in the foreground so you should not have an always running activity. The fact that your setup works before Android 11 is a quirk and not a feature of the previous versions of the OS.

You should instead move the always running code into a background service (or a foreground service if you need the code to run even after the app is killed).

If you're really intent on finding the caller, you'll need to log the stacktrace inside of the activity's `onDestroy()` and either write it to a file that you can retrieve from the user's phone or upload the log to a custom web application endpoint or through a third-party service.

You can get a string representation of the current stacktrace with `Log.getStackTrace(Exception())` or print it to the standard error stream with `Thread.dumpStack()`

Comment: tried with Thread.dumpStack() but it's only 1 entry long (the call itself)